# Abide Required tag in simple-form without "data-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, zurb-foundation-6

With Foundation 6 and Abide I want to have this tag in a simple-form form:

```
<input class="string optional" pattern="text" type="text" name="service[street_address]" id="service_street_address" required>
```

with a `required` attribute.

I tried this:

```
<%= service.input_field :street_address, data: {:required => ''}, pattern:"text" %>
```

but the the `required` tag becomes `data-required` and breaks Abide validation:

```
<input data-required="" class="string optional" pattern="text" type="text" name="service[street_address]" id="service_street_address">
```

Is there any way to have only `required` or `required=""` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If required: true doesn't work, try:

`<%= service.text_field :postal_box, required: "required", pattern: "text" %>`

Answer (score 0):

"Required" becomes "data-required" because you've put it inside data: {}. What data: {} does is create data-* tags for you. So it's no surprise that the end input is "data-required". If you're looking for "required", then you're using the wrong method.

With a normal form_for tag, you can pass the attributes as options in the hash, like so:

`<%= service.input_field :street_address, required: true, pattern:"text" %>`

With simple_form, because simple_form creates a wrapper and a label automatically, you have to clarify that you're adding the attribute to the *input*, like so:

`<%= service.input_field :street_address, input_html: { required: true }, pattern:"text" %>`

I believe that, in your case, input_field is a form_for, and not a simple_form tag. So try the first method, and if it doesn't work, try the second.

(As a side note, you'll notice that the input it produces has this html:

`<input required="required">`

instead of:

`<input required>`

But these are exactly the same)

Comment: Thanks Samy for your answer, I've tried both methods but the first results in class="string required" and the second in input_html="{:required=>true}"